# Is it possible to detect key event in opened ComboBox?

Tags: qt, combobox, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

I want to implement some kind of search in `ComboBox` with lots of items. It contains ~ 500 lines, ordered by name. So I want to do it in manner when user press `A` key it shows only lines begin with `A...` , when then press `s` it shows lines begin with `As...` etc. But `Key` events only work if `ComboBox` is closed. If dropdown list is shown no key event occurs, except some inner events like arrows and Esc/Enter.

Any ideas how to do that? Any advices and suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need so hard code, there is extremely easy and fast solution. There is special class for autocompletion - `QCompleter`. So answer is simple, create `QCompleter` with needed data and set it, to comboBox using `setCompleter()` setter.

```
QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(mdl, this);//mdl is a model with some data
completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
ui->comboBox->setCompleter(completer);
```

Result without completer(original comboBox):

[image]

Result with completer:

[image]

Comment: You can simply install the completer directly on the QCombobox, no reason to do the const_cast dance and access the lineEdit. `comboBox->setCompleter( completer )` http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#setCompleter

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn Yes, you are absolutely right, didn't notice this method, noticed only lineEdit(), so I should do const_cast dance... Anyways, thank you very much, I edited my answer

Comment: OP asked about ComboBox in QtQuick, not QComboBox in QtWitdgets

Comment: @GrecKo Hmm, it seems that you are right...With QtQuick it seems to be impossible, with c++ it can be done much and much easier. Unfortunately I have no option but to wait for OP reaction.

Comment: There is autocompletion on ComboBox in qml too, just make it editable and assign it a model, but it doesn't work like OP asked (not editable while the list is open and doesn't show the filtered results)

Comment: Uhm...definitely right! I was just testing it. Put it as an answer @GrecKo. Still you don't have the list, as a `QCompleter` has.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers! Yes I know about `QCompleter`. But as @GrecKo said I need it in `QML`. It would be great feature in `QML` but now it's impossible.

Comment: You can go for the `QComboBox` embedding...even though I think it's not worth the effort. A custom approach would be the solution (and should be quite easy to implement).

Comment: Yes @BaCaRoZzo, you are right, I also desided to implement my own item - just Button + ListView.

Comment: I would say `TextField` + bottom-anchored `Flickable` with inside a `Column`. That sounds better to be. Well, I guess it's just a matter of taste. :)